# Clearing DIV with float

Tags: css

I have a div (navigation) that is "float:left;".
After this div main content comes. And second divs comes over the first one.

If I add style="clear:both;" after the first dif, then it works.
However, i wonder if this is the right way to do this, this is my only question.

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>...
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="content-wrapper"></div>    

.nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;    
}

.nav li{
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 2px;
}

.nav li a{        
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;        
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color: #3b3d49;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: floated elements need to be cleared if you want elements to appear properly below them

Comment: Its fine and correct as far as i know. Put it through a W3c validator...

Comment: I think questions on best practice fit [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) better.

Comment: You have 3 divs under each other? Why dont you just remove `float:left` form the first div instead of adding `clear:both` to the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that works fine. However, you don't need another element to clear the content, you can add the style to the content wrapper.

In your style sheet:

```
#content-wrapper { clear: both; }
```

---

Another approach is to add a container around the floating element, and make it contain its children using the `overflow` style:

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">text</a></li>...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
</div>
```

Then in your style sheet add:

```
.nav-container { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The main use of the above mentioned `"clear:both"`

The clear property specifies which sides of an element where other floating elements are not allowed.

```
"clear:both"
```

means No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, cleaning floats with `clear:both;` is a pretty standard way of doing this, yes.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best way, just add class .group to your container

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is correct to see this example from the creators of html

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<br clear="all" />` for short hand. And another way is that you could use clearfix method, you could search it on google for the best. this is the method that @conner explained it.